# How to wrap a method that takes variable-length arguments?

Tags: ruby

Suppose there's a method called `foo` that takes variable-length arguments.

```
def foo(*args)
  # Implementation omitted
end
```

And I want to wrap the method with `bar`.

```
def bar(*args)
# Will call `foo` at some point
# `foo(args)` isn't satisfactory.
end
```

How do I call `foo` inside `bar` so that if I call `bar` with `bar(1,2,3)`, `foo(1,2,3)` is also called?

Some constraints are:

1. I could not change the code for `foo`.
2. `foo` and `bar` should have exactly the same signature.

Of course I could do `foo(args)` inside `bar`. But if that's the case, for `foo`, what it will receive is an Array of Array instead of an Array.

Thanks.

Comment: You use the splat operator: `foo(*args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a splat operator (`*`) as Blender commented: It converts an array into arguments.

```
def bar(*args)
  foo(*args)
end
```